# The value of the "id" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length

Tags: apex, visualforce

It fails right here:

> ```
>       <apex:inputField value="{!Rec.supplier.id}" styleClass="rate" required="true"/>
> ```

My code is:

```
                Public      List<sobject>           Selectedmeters      {get;set;}
@TestVisible    Public      List<loggingWrapper>    contractWrapper     {get;set;}


@TestVisible Public Class loggingWrapper{
    Public      double                  AQ                  {get;set;}
    Public      double                  commission_per_year {get;set;}
    Public      double                  commission_per_kwh  {get;set;}
    Public      account                 supplier            {get;set;}
    Public      id                      meterID             {get;set;}
    Public      string                  unique_identifier   {get;set;}   
    Public      id                      contractID          {get;set;}           
    Public      date                    csd                 {get;set;}     
    Public      date                    ced                 {get;set;}     
    Public loggingWrapper(id meterID, string unique_identifier, account supplier,  double aq, double commission_per_year, double commission_per_kwh, date csd, date ced){
        supplier = supplier;
        unique_identifier=unique_identifier;
        aq = aq;
        commission_per_kwh=commission_per_kwh;
        commission_per_year=commission_per_year;
        meterID=meterID;
        ced = ced;
        csd=csd;
    }
}  

@TestVisible Public List<loggingWrapper> getContractsGrid(){
    list <contract__c> contractList = [select id, meter__r.id, contract_status__c, meter__r.UID__c from contract__c where id in: Selectedmeters];
    contractWrapper = New List<loggingWrapper>();
    for(contract__c contract: contractList){
        string unique_identifier=contract.meter__r.UID__c;
        id meterID= contract.meter__r.id;
        contractWrapper.add(
            new loggingWrapper(
                meterID,
                unique_identifier, null, null, null,null,null,null                                  
            ));
    }
    return contractWrapper;
}
```

I am struggling to understand this one.

**Update**: Added to my wrapper:

> ```
>         account tempAcc = new account();
>         contractWrapper.add( 
>             new loggingWrapper(
>                 meterIDtmp,
>                 unique_identifiertmp, tempAcc, null, null,null,null,null,lineIDtmp
> ```

Setting inputField value to rec.supplier does not find the binding.

Setting inputField value to rec.supplier.id or .name works, but does not show the lookup icon.

Comment: Normally you would not reference the Id field of an SObject in an inputField, you would reference a relationship field like a lookup or master-detail.  But to your question, I would imagine this is occuring because you're attempting to dereference Account.Id when Account is null.  Is this occurring before or after you submit?

Comment: That's before I submit. I tried removing .id, but I get error: Could not resolve the entity from &lt;apex:inputField&gt; value binding '{!Rec.supplier}'.  &lt;apex:inputField&gt; can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

Comment: This error is because inputField must use a field on an instance of an SObject, where as you're now referencing the actual Account SObject.

Comment: I really do not understand. InputText just gives you textual field, I need a lookup field.

Comment: Does your Meter object have a lookup to Account?  Are you trying to provide the user a way to set or change the supplier for a given Meter?

Comment: Contract__c has a a lookup to Account.

Comment: as an aside, if your controller methods are public, they don't need to be annotated `@TestVisible`

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer to your question is that you're attempting to dereference the Id field of supplier in your page, but supplier is null.  If you set supplier = new Account() instead of null, you would at least be able to render the page without error.

That said, inputField is not normally intended to bind to the Id value of an SObject.  If you do as I just suggested, you'll notice that it does not render a visible form element.  Even if supplier had a value for Id, it would display the value as read-only text.  The standard lookup functionality is available to relationship fields only, not the object's Id field.

If you want the standard functionality that a lookup field provides, you must provide an object and field to the value attribute such that:

1. The object is a child of the object that you want to look up to.
2. The field is a relationship field such as lookup or master-detail.

So as an exmaple, I would need to use {!Contact.AccountId} instead of {!Account.Id} or {!Contact.Account} or {!Contact.Account.Id}.

In your case, perhaps you can bring back Account__c in your Contract__c query (or whatever you named the account field) and add a property to your LoggingWrapper and set it to an instance of Contract__c.  Then in your page, bind to {!contractPropertyName.Account__c}.

Comment: See my update. I've added current_supplier__c (which is a lookup to Account) to SOQL query, and added new Account(); to wrapper.

Comment: I do not see an update to your OP that uses current_supplier__c, but you're still binding to non-relationship fields.  Id and Name are not relationship fields.  current_supplier__c is a lookup relationship field FROM the Contract__c TO the Account, so if I had a Contract__c property named varContract I could bind to it as {!varContract.current_supplier__c}, and that inputField would display a lookup icon that would modify the value of current_supplier__c for that specific Contract__c record.

Comment: But how do you add that property to a wrapper? I thought adding Account(); would imply it's a relationship field?

Comment: Ok I got it. I added the whole Contract__c sObject to the wrapper and accessing it from there.